# Execute android build tasks in custom tasks

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I wanted to remove the project makefile and write some nice gradle tasks.
I need to execute the following tasks, in this order:

1. Clean
2. Increment version
3. Build
4. Upload

#1, #3 and #4 are tasks from android and plugin (bintray) while #2 is a custom task. Here is what I have so far:

```
task releaseMajor {
    doLast {
        clean.execute()
        build.execute()
        incrementVersion.execute()
        bintrayUpload.execute()
    }
}
```

The run order was not so great as I think `clean` was run after `build`. And `binrayUpload` was running without flavor (`release`). I've also tried to use `dependsOn` without success (order not working).

I couldn't find in Gradle doc how to do this properly. When execute in the right order, from CLI, everything works perfectly.

Comment: How did you use `dependsOn` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `mustRunAfter`, or `finalizedBy` for finer order control:

```
task releaseMajor (dependsOn: ['clean', 'build', 'incrementVersion', 'bintrayUpload'])
build.mustRunAfter clean
incrementVersion.mustRunAfter build
bintrayUpload.mustRunAfter incrementVersion
```

Comment: Doing this wouldn't run for example build after every clean?

Comment: No. See section 17.5 [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks, works great. So if I'm right, `dependsOn` is tasks that will be run in `releaseMajor` but the order is not respected until be specified it after. And according to the doc, in everyday execution, `build` would not be run after `clean`. I've read twice the doc and it wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: I've some issue using this: I have `releaseMajor` AND `releaseMinor`. `releaseMinor` is the same as major plus incrementing version. The script is run on correctly (increment is done before everything) but the released aar is the old version before incrementing it. Result is here https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/29bea87c097698d10a4f

Comment: the `mustRunAfter` lines are not tied to the task definition, you don't have to do the same rule twice. https://gist.github.com/foragerr/ea7e7a3d4f63607bb70b

Comment: The issue you're having seems unrelated to order of execution, please check the implementation of your incrementVersionName and if it is actually updating the version that bintrayUpload is using. Raise a new question with code from both tasks.

Comment: I'm changing the library/module version (`android.defaultConfig.versionName`), before a clean is done. maybe the build is not done properly? or gradle detect it has "UP-TO-DATE"

Answer (score 0):

Tried this

```
task clean {
    println 'clean task executing'
}
task incrementVersion (dependsOn:"clean"){
    println 'incrementVersion task executing'
}
task building (dependsOn:"incrementVersion"){
    println 'build task executing'
}
task bintrayUpload (dependsOn:"building") {
    println 'bintrayUpload task executing'
}
```

The output was

```
clean task executing
incrementVersion task executing
build task executing
bintrayUpload task executing
```

and executed `./gradlew bintryUpload`

Comment: I'm using already done task from android named `clean` or `build`. I can redefine it.

Comment: Chaining `dependsOn` is not a good solution in this scenario because, you can no longer run each individual task if you want to, without triggering the tasks up the chain first. OPs tasks really are normally independent tasks.